# how to stop target machine from actively refusing my connection

Tags: c#, api, console, connection, target

i am trying to post to an API of flights that I build a new flight from a console application under the same solution and I keep getting this exception "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

I believe the problem isn't from my code but anyway... this is my code:

```
private async void CreateNewArrival(Flight flight)
    {
        string url = $"http://localhost:5149/api/flights";
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, flight); //the problematic row
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        else Console.WriteLine("Arrival was sent to api");

    }
```

thanks everyone!

Comment: Two obvious reasons for this would be there is nothing listening on that port or the connection is being blocked by a firewall.

Comment: "from a console application under the same solution" In Visual Studio, right click on the solution and choose "Set Startup Projects" to launch and debug multiple projects at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Retired Ninja is correct.

This does not directly answer your question, but when something like this happens me, I usually just refuse to give up. Keep trying something new until you figure it out.

If you are doing API work, a tool like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) can be very helpful. If you are sure your API project is running, you should be able to call it from Postman. You may need to temporarily disable firewall or antivirus until you can get it working.

Once it is working with Postman, triple check your URL and port in your C# code. Place a breakpoint in your code and inspect the url in your HttpResponseMessage (an HTTP client can have a base url set).